# Unable to implement infinite scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to use infinite scrolling on my custom listings page. I am trying to create this using AJAX.

The issue I am facing is that the request is being made even if I move my mouse a little after reaching 70% of the screen which is causing a huge load on the web page. Ideally it shouldn't be until the toolbar HTML is updated. The AJAX should then load the next page.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    require([
  'jquery'
], function($) {
  var next_page = '';
  var isloading = false;
   var nextPage = '';
  var url      = window.location.href; 
  var nextPageBaseUrl = url+'?p=';

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= ($(document).height() - $(window).height()) * 0.7 && !isloading) {

        var nextPage = $(".pages-items li.current").next("li").find("a span").eq(1).html();
      next_page = nextPageBaseUrl + nextPage;

      console.log(next_page);
      isloading = true

      $.ajax({
        url: next_page,
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data) {
          this.isloading = false;
          this.nextPage = this.nextPage + 1;
          $('ol.product-items').append($(data).find('div.products-grid').html());
          $('.infinite-loader').html($(data).find('div.infinite-loader').html());
          $('.toolbar-products').html($(data).find('div.toolbar-products').html());
        }.bind(this)
      });
    };
  });
});
</script>
```

```html
<ul class="items pages-items" aria-labelledby="paging-label">
  <li class="item current">
    <strong class="page">
      <span class="label">test</span>
      <span>1</span>
    </strong>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <a href="https://www.test.com/test?p=2" class="page">
      <span class="label">Page</span>
      <span>2</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <a href="https://www.test.com/test?p=3" class="page">
      <span class="label">Page</span>
      <span>3</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your question title was about something completely different than the description. I edited it for you

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Sorry about that. Thanks. I hope my question is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to restrict further Ajax calls while one is already fireing?
Have you tried using a variable, something like this below, see the `isloading` variable. `nextPage` and `nextPageBaseUrl` is used for the next page logic.

```
require([
  'jquery'
], function($) {
  var next_page = '';
  var isloading = false;
  var nextPage = $(".pages-items li.current").next("li").find("a span").eq(1).html();
  var nextPageBaseUrl = 'https://www.test.com/test?p=';

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= ($(document).height() - $(window).height()) * 0.7 && !isloading) {

      next_page = nextPageBaseUrl + nextPage;

      console.log(next_page);
      isloading = true

      $.ajax({
        url: next_page,
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data) {
          this.isloading = false;
          this.nextPage = this.nextPage + 1;
          $('ol.product-items').append($(data).find('div.products-grid').html());
          $('.infinite-loader').html($(data).find('div.infinite-loader').html());
          $('.toolbar-products').html($(data).find('div.toolbar-products').html());
        }.bind(this)
      });
    };
  });
});
```

Comment: Yes, you got my question. But I do not want to fire ajax till the first one is firing. But I want the ajax to not repeat. Like if p=2 is firing it should only fire p=3 that too after p=2 is loaded.

Comment: So you see that toolbar will have updated which make current = 2, and hence 3 will be the href to target.

Comment: The code worked correctly for p=2, but after loading the data p=2, it stopped, whereas it should load p=3 when I scrolled down. Can you please help. I think I am almost there. I checked console.log it still came up with p=2.

Comment: I guess you sould also update your `next_page` variable when success has fired.

Comment: Can you please help me on how can I do that?

Comment: I am using the code the way you shared, its not loading next page. I have update my question to the way I am using it, can you please check once, if I am making any mistake?

Comment: Guessing that `var url = window.location.href;  ` is not where your API is located?

Comment: the p is not updating is the issue I think?

Comment: You also reset the `nextPage` variable each time with `var nextPage = $(".pages-items li.current").next("li").find("a span").eq(1).html();`, you should probably remove that.

Comment: Just move the assignment outside of the function, like my updated answer.

Comment: I have tried both ways, inside function and outside, but not working. I think the p variable value needs updating. But dont know how will that be updated

Answer (score 0):

This line of code makes it load after 70% of screen height.

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() >= ($(document).height() - $(window).height()) * 0.7) {
```

Instead use this -

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() >= ($(document).height() - $(window).height())) {
```

Comment: What difference will it make?

Comment: When you subtract height and then multiply the same by 0.7, you are defining cut off at 70% of the screen height. If you must, try 0.95 in place of 0.7.

Comment: That is not the issue, if you see my question. Its related to ajax.